# Compile QGIS / Can't find Qt Cryptographic Architecture

Tags: qgis, windows, compile

I'm trying to compile QGIS-master 2.12 for the first time following the INSTALL guide (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL). 
I'm stucked while compiling with the "CMake Error at cmake/FindQCA.cmake:64".

### Here is my environment:

- Windows XP SP3
- Qt 4.8.7
- Qt Creator 3.6.0
- Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
- Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4
- CMake 3.0.2
- OpenSSL 1.0.2f
- OSGeo4W (expat, fcgi, gdal, grass, gsl-devel, iconv, pyqt4, qt4-devel, qwt5-devel-qt4, sip, spatialite, libspatialindex-devel, python-qscintilla)
- Cygwin (bison, flex, git)
- I tried to install QCA from the source but I can't get it work.

Any advice on how to go ahead?

### Here is the log when I try to compile QGIS in QtCreator:

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1

-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe

-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- QGIS version: 2.13.0 Master (21300)

-- Could not find GRASS 6

-- Could not find GRASS 7

-- Found Proj: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/proj.lib

-- Found GEOS: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/geos_c.lib (3.5.0)

-- Found GDAL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/gdal_i.lib (2.0.2)

-- Found Expat: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/libexpat.lib

-- Found Spatialindex: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialindex_i.lib

-- Found Qwt: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/qwt5.lib (5.2.1)

-- Found Sqlite3: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/sqlite3_i.lib

-- Found PostgreSQL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/libpq.lib

-- Found SpatiaLite: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib

-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)

-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 

-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY) 

-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY) (found version "4.0.2")

-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 

-- Found Qt version: 4.8.6

-- Touch support disabled

-- Found QScintilla2: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/qscintilla2.lib (2.8.4) 

CMake Error at cmake/FindQCA.cmake:64 (message):   Could not find QCA Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:312 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "//mac/Home/Desktop/build-QGIS-master-Desktop-Default/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "//mac/Home/Desktop/build-QGIS-master-Desktop-Default/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Did you install the qca development package from osgeo4w?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn could you add that as an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the qca development package. On windows this can be done from the osgeo4w setup.